# Running XCode on Linux through SSH

Tags: ios, linux, xcode, macos, ssh

If I am SSH'ed into a Mac/OSX machine from a Linux machine, is it possible to compile and run Objective C applications? Could I open up XCode within the Linux machine and interact with it? Is there anyway to achieve something similar without using VNC software?

I have tried SSHing into a Mac and then opening XCode through the terminal, but it only opens XCode on my mac and not on my linux machine.

Comment: SSH is a Secure SHell, I'm not sure you understood what you are trying to do. I guess you need a virtual desktop or something similar

Comment: Short version, too trivial to write as a "real" answer: No.